# SharpSVN: How to get working copy path from repository URI?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

SharpSVN has `SvnClient.GetUriFromWorkingCopy` to get a repository URI from the path of a working copy, but I don't see a function that does the reverse--there's no `GetWorkingCopyFromUri`.

Assuming there is one, how do I get the name of the working copy from a repository URI?

TIA

Comment: Well how would the Uri know about it? I can put up 10 working copies to the same svn in 10 different locations on my pc. You could scan all folders and look for an .svn and try if a `svn info` on this location works - but what is the point.

Comment: Wow, that's right. The tendency is to think in terms of a 1:1 relationship between a tree in the repository and the local tree you're working with, but of course that's not the case at all. I'll have to think of another way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter points out, this is not possible because there can be multiple working copies of a file in the repository.